# Solr More Like This Handler: Any way to specify which fields are more important than others?

Tags: solr, morelikethis

I'm constructing a 'more like this' query using Solr's MoreLikeThisHandler (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis). I'm asking Solr to look at multiple fields. Is there a way to tell Solr that terms appearing in one field is more important than another?

For example:

```
mlt.fl=title,description
```

Is there any way to tell Solr that terms appearing in *title* is 3 times more relevant than *description*?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mlt.qf setting like this

```
<str name="mlt.qf">field_name^3.0</str>  <!-- x3 boost -->
```

Here's the documentation
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis